# Fix for restricted non-sdk in Android Q

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, android-10.0

I want to set a field. However, the non SDK interfaces which have been restricted under Android Q has an interface I am using i.e. `Ljava/lang/Integer;->value:I`
The suggested way by Google is to use public API instead. i.e. `java.lang.Integer.intValue()`

However, I need to do the following:

```
c = env->FindClass("java/lang/Integer");
id = env->GetFieldID(c, "value", "I");
env->SetIntField(a, id, b);
```

Even if I use java.lang.Integer.intValue(), I'll only get the value and not the reference. How can I set the field then?

Comment: What are the `a` and `b`? Anyway, I don't really think you may get a reference on JNI value.

Comment: Can you be more concrete? Especially the API you are trying to use.

Comment: `a` is a `jobject` and `b` is a count. I want to set the int field which can be done by the above code. However, Google has restricted the non SDK interface `Ljava/lang/Integer;->value:I` in [link](https://developer.android.com/preview/non-sdk-q#greylist-now-restricted) and I need to use intValue() in the Integer class. The Integer class doesn't have a setter so it isn't possible for me to set the value.

Comment: Modifying a non mutable class is not a good idea. You should create a new integer object assigning the new value.

Comment: Actually, my app crashes because of the restriction for non SDK interface, because it does not find the field "I". My question is how can I reproduce the above code in an alternate way. Google suggests to use the public API but I'm not able to figure out how to.